# Discoknights game structure

Tags: python, performance, pygame, adventure-game

I'm building a game with Pygame, a simple turn-based strategy game where on each turn a character can move and/or perform an action. I have a somewhat good structure for the game on the background, and pygame provides the gui for that. Below is the code of the main file. I think the structure of `main.py` is quite terrible at the moment. The question is then, how do I alter that (including the main loop) to a better one. Also, what can I do to improve the performance?

[Here's everything else](https://github.com/roopepal/discoknights/tree/2fa2e7b47320e25a34a8c07efbaae0aa82c1cd6e) if you need to take a look at the background logic.

```
def map_to_screen(x,y, offset_x=0, offset_y=0):
    screen_x = (x - y) * (tile_w / 2) + offset_x
    screen_y = (x + y) * (tile_h / 2) + offset_y
    return screen_x, screen_y

def screen_to_map(x,y, offset_x=0, offset_y=0):
    x -= ( offset_x + tile_w / 2 )
    y -= offset_y
    x = x / 2
    map_x = (y + x)/(tile_h)
    map_y = (y - x)/(tile_h)
    if map_x < 0:
        map_x -= 1
    if map_y < 0:
        map_y -= 1    
    return int(map_x), int(map_y)

def square_clicked(screen_x, screen_y):
    x = screen_x
    y = screen_y
    map_x = ( x / (tile_w / 2) + y / (tile_h / 2) ) / 2
    map_y = ( y / (tile_h / 2) - (y / (tile_w / 2)) ) / 2
    return (map_x, map_y)

def load_sprites():
    sprites = {}

    # For each squaretype, load sprites that are not loaded
    for squaretype in m.squaretypes:
        if m.squaretypes[squaretype].sprite not in sprites:
            sprites[m.squaretypes[squaretype].sprite] = pygame.image.load(m.squaretypes[squaretype].sprite).convert_alpha()
            print("Successfully loaded sprite '{:}'".format(m.squaretypes[squaretype].sprite))

    # For each object type, load sprites that are not loaded
    for object_type in m.object_types:
        if m.object_types[object_type].sprite not in sprites:
            sprites[m.object_types[object_type].sprite] = pygame.image.load(m.object_types[object_type].sprite).convert_alpha()
            print("Successfully loaded sprite '{:}'".format(m.object_types[object_type].sprite))

    # For each character, load all sprites that are not already loaded
    for character in m.characters:
        for sprite in character.stand_sprites:
            if character.stand_sprites[sprite] not in sprites:
                sprites[character.stand_sprites[sprite]] = pygame.image.load(character.stand_sprites[sprite]).convert_alpha()
                print("Successfully loaded sprite '{:}'".format(character.stand_sprites[sprite]))

        for sprite_list in character.walk_sprites:
            for sprite in character.walk_sprites[sprite_list]:
                if sprite not in sprites:
                    sprites[sprite] = pygame.image.load(sprite).convert_alpha()
                    print("Successfully loaded sprite '{:}'".format(sprite))

    return sprites

def render_squares(surface):        
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    for x in range(m.width):
        for y in range(m.height):
            square = m.get_square_at(Coordinates(x,y))
            screen_x, screen_y = map_to_screen(x,y)
            surface.blit(sprites[square.squaretype.sprite], (screen_x + map_offset_x, screen_y))

def render_range(surface):
    for sq in within_range:
        sq_mx, sq_my = sq.location.x, sq.location.y
        sq_sx, sq_sy = map_to_screen(sq_mx, sq_my, map_offset_x, map_offset_y)
        if selected_action:
            if selected_action.type == Action.HEAL:
                surface.blit( heal_target_img, (sq_sx, sq_sy) )
            else:
                surface.blit( action_target_img, (sq_sx, sq_sy) )
        else:
            surface.blit( selected_img, (sq_sx, sq_sy) )

def render_characters_and_objects(surface, walking=None, scr_loc=None, sprite_counter=None):
    # collect dirty rects
    dirty = []

    # For each square on the map, check if there's a character and if yes, draw it. Do this in the order of squares to maintain proper drawing order.
    for x in range(m.width):
        for y in range(m.height):
            square = m.get_square_at(Coordinates(x,y))
            character = square.character
            # Translate coordinates
            screen_x, screen_y = map_to_screen(x,y, map_offset_x, map_offset_y)

            if square.character and not square.character.dead:
                if character.facing == direction.UP: facing = "up"
                elif character.facing == direction.DOWN: facing = "down"
                elif character.facing == direction.LEFT: facing = "left"
                elif character.facing == direction.RIGHT: facing = "right"

                if character == walking:
                    # Draw sprite based on the direction facing
                    if character.walk_sprites:
                        dirty.append(surface.blit(sprites[character.walk_sprites[facing][sprite_counter]], (scr_loc[0] + character_offset_x, scr_loc[1] + character_offset_y))) 
                    else:
                        dirty.append(surface.blit(sprites[character.stand_sprites[facing]], (scr_loc[0] + character_offset_x, scr_loc[1] + character_offset_y))) 
                else:
                    dirty.append( surface.blit(sprites[character.stand_sprites[facing]], (screen_x + character_offset_x, screen_y + character_offset_y)) )
                    #dirty.append(pygame.Rect(48,48, screen_x+character_offset_x,screen_y+character_offset_y))

            elif square.object:
                dirty.append( surface.blit(sprites[square.object.type.sprite], (screen_x + square.object.type.offset_x, screen_y + square.object.type.offset_y)) )

    return dirty

def render_info_text(surface, text_to_display):
    text = font.render(text_to_display, 1, (10, 10, 10))
    textpos = text.get_rect()
    textpos.move_ip(0,screen_h - 16)
    textpos.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
    bgpos = pygame.Rect(0,0,(screen_w - 128*2 - 14), 28)
    bgpos.centerx = textpos.centerx
    surface.blit(bottom_bar.subsurface(bgpos), (bgpos.x, screen_h-28))
    surface.blit(text, textpos)
    return textpos

def render_char_info(surface, wanted=None):
    if wanted:
        if not isinstance(wanted, list):
            wanted = [wanted]
    else:
        wanted = m.characters

    count = 0
    ai_count = 1
    dirty = []

    for character in m.characters:

        if character in wanted:
            if character.has_turn():
                char_info_surface = char_info_turn.copy()
            elif character.dead:
                char_info_surface = char_info_dead.copy()
            else:
                char_info_surface = char_info.copy()

            head_image = pygame.image.load(character.stand_sprites["right"]).convert_alpha()
            head_image.set_clip(pygame.Rect(0,0, 20,20))

            char_info_surface.blit(head_image, (5,5), (8,5,24,24))

            text_line_1 = str(character.health) + "/"
            text_line_2 = str(character.max_health)

            t1 = font.render(text_line_1, 1, (10,10,10))
            t2 = font.render(text_line_2, 1, (10,10,10))

            t1_pos = t1.get_rect()
            t1_pos.move_ip(0,36)
            t1_pos.centerx = char_info_surface.get_rect().centerx
            char_info_surface.blit(t1, t1_pos)

            t2_pos = t2.get_rect()
            t2_pos.move_ip(0,46)
            t2_pos.centerx = char_info_surface.get_rect().centerx
            char_info_surface.blit(t2, t2_pos)            

            if character.ai:
                surface.blit(char_info_surface, (screen_w - ai_count * 34 - 5, 7))
                dirty.append(pygame.Rect(32,58, screen_w - ai_count * 34 - 5,7))
            else:
                surface.blit(char_info_surface, (7 + count* 34, 7))
                dirty.append(pygame.Rect(32,58, 7+count*34,7))

        if character.ai: ai_count += 1
        else: count += 1    

    return dirty

def render_bottom_bar(surface):        
    #blit background bar
    bar = pygame.image.load("graphics/bottom_bar.gif").convert()
    for i in range(surface.get_width() // 4):
        surface.blit(bar, (i*4, 0))

def render_end_turn_button(surface):
    if end_turn_button.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            end_turn_button.pushed = True
        else:    
            end_turn_button.hovered = True
    else:
        end_turn_button.hovered = False
        end_turn_button.pushed = False

    end_turn_button.render_to(surface)        
    #return the button for dirty rects and mouse recognition
    return end_turn_button.rect

def render_action_menu(surface):
    # blit menu bg
    actions_menu = pygame.image.load("graphics/actions_menu.gif").convert_alpha()
    surface.blit(actions_menu, (7, screen_h - 103))

    if selected_character:
        use_buttons = []
        count = 0
        for action in selected_character.actions:
            use_button = ui.Button(ui.action_bg, ui.action_bg_hover, ui.action_bg_push, (20, screen_h - 94 + count * 26))
            use_buttons.append(use_button)

            if use_button.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                    use_button.pushed = True
                else:    
                    use_button.hovered = True
            else:
                use_button.hovered = False
                use_button.pushed = False

            use_button.render_to(surface)

            text = action.description + " (" + str(action.strength) + ")"
            text = font.render(text, False, (10,10,10))
            text_pos = text.get_rect()
            text_pos.move_ip(65, screen_h - 84 + count * 26)
            surface.blit(text, text_pos)

            count += 1

        return use_buttons
    return []

def render_effect_text(surface, count, text_surface):
    if text_surface:
        scr_loc = map_to_screen(effect_text_loc.x, effect_text_loc.y)
        x = scr_loc[0] + 32 - text_surface.get_width()/2 + map_offset_x
        y = scr_loc[1] - 40 - count*1 + map_offset_y
        location = (x, y)

        if count > 10:
            opacity = 255 - 12 * count
        else:
            opacity = 255

        #surface.blit(map_surface, (map_offset_x + map_fix_x, map_offset_y))
        blit_alpha(surface, text_surface, location, opacity)

        count += 1
        if count > 20:
            count = 0
            return count, None

    return count, text_surface

def get_effect_text(action):
    if action.type == Action.HEAL:
        text = "+" + str(action.strength)
        color = (10, 200, 10)
    else:
        text = "-" + str(action.strength)
        color = (200, 10, 10)

    text_surface = med_font.render(text, False, color)
    return text_surface

def blit_alpha(target, source, location, opacity):
    '''Blits opaque element while keeping per pixel alpha in other parts of the surface.'''
    x = location[0]
    y = location[1]
    temp = pygame.Surface((source.get_width(), source.get_height())).convert_alpha()
    temp.blit(target, (-x, -y))
    temp.blit(source, (0, 0))
    temp.set_alpha(opacity)        
    target.blit(temp, location)

def blit_map(surface):
    return surface.blit(map_surface, (map_offset_x + map_fix_x, map_offset_y))

#Game starts
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 40

#read config from files
r = ConfigReader()
f = open('map_config', 'r')
map_config = r.read_config(f)
f.close()
f = open('character_config', 'r')
character_config = r.read_config(f)
f.close()

m = r.build_from_config(map_config, character_config)
ai = Ai(m)

#set window size
screen_w = 1280
screen_h = 768
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_w, screen_h))

#initiate fonts
font = pygame.font.Font("fonts/coders_crux.ttf", 14)
med_font = pygame.font.Font("fonts/coders_crux.ttf", 16)

#load sprites
selected_img = pygame.image.load('graphics/selected.gif').convert_alpha()
action_target_img = pygame.image.load('graphics/action_selected.gif').convert_alpha()
heal_target_img = pygame.image.load('graphics/heal_selected.gif').convert_alpha()
char_info = pygame.image.load("graphics/char_info.gif").convert_alpha()
char_info_turn = pygame.image.load("graphics/char_info_has_turn.gif").convert_alpha()
char_info_dead = pygame.image.load("graphics/char_info_dead.gif").convert_alpha()
sprites = load_sprites()

#prepare the map and rendering offsets
tile_w = 64
tile_h = 32
map_w = (m.width + m.height) * tile_w / 2
map_h = (m.width + m.height) * tile_h / 2 + 8
map_offset_x = map_w / 2 - tile_w / 2
map_offset_y = 0
character_offset_x = 13
character_offset_y = -30
#create a separate surface for the map and render squares on it
map_surface = pygame.Surface((map_w, map_h))
render_squares(map_surface)

bottom_menu_rect = pygame.Rect(0, screen_h-128, screen_w, 128)
bottom_bar = pygame.Surface((screen_w, 28))
render_bottom_bar(bottom_bar)
end_turn_button = ui.Button(ui.end_turn_bg, ui.end_turn_bg_hover, ui.end_turn_bg_push, (screen_w - 135, screen_h - 71))

#prepare pause menu
options = [ ui.MenuOption("NEW GAME"),
            ui.MenuOption("QUIT") ]
[ option.set_rect(screen, options) for option in options ]

#prepare the game loop control variables
done = False
selected_character = m.turn_controller.current_character
selected_action = None
mouse_pos = None
within_range = selected_character.within_range(selected_character.range)   
text_to_display = None
saved_text = None
did_update_already = False
did_move_already = False
effect_fade_count = 0
effect_text = None
dirty_rects = []
refresh_map = False
walk = False
action = False
path_to_move = False
square_clicked = None

#Initial render
screen.fill((0,0,0))
#map, the map_fix_x fixes horizontal positioning, and the offsets center the map on the screen
map_fix_x = tile_w / 2 - map_surface.get_rect().w/2
map_offset_x += screen_w / 2 - map_w / 2
map_offset_y += screen_h / 2 - map_h / 2

in_menu = True
paused = False
plr_won = False    
ai_won = False

#milliseconds from last frame
new_time, old_time = None, None    

#set a wait timer to leave time between AI actions
ai_delay = 1000
wait_ms = False


#start main loop
while not done:

    clock.tick(fps)
    dirty_rects = []
    did_update_already = False

    #recognize winner
    plr_characters_alive = 0
    ai_characters_alive = 0
    for c in m.characters:
        if not c.ai and not c.dead:
            plr_characters_alive += 1
        elif c.ai and not c.dead:
            ai_characters_alive += 1
    if plr_characters_alive == 0:
        ai_won = True
        in_menu = True
    elif ai_characters_alive == 0:
        plr_won = True
        in_menu = True

    #---------------
    # Menu loop

    while in_menu:
        #draw menu and options    
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        if plr_won or ai_won:
            if plr_won:
                winner = ui.super_large_font.render("You won!", True, (255,255,255))
            else:
                winner = ui.super_large_font.render("You lost!", True, (255,255,255))
            winner_rect = winner.get_rect()
            winner_rect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
            winner_rect.y = 20
            screen.blit(winner, winner_rect)

            #prevent action effect text from showing after pressing new game
            effect_text = None

        if paused:
            resume = ui.large_font.render("Press Esc to resume game.", True, (255,255,255))
            resume_rect = resume.get_rect()
            resume_rect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
            resume_rect.y = 20
            screen.blit(resume, resume_rect)

        for option in options:
            if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                option.hover = True
            else:
                option.hover = False
            option.draw()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                in_menu = False
                done = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE and paused and not (plr_won or ai_won):
                paused = False
                in_menu = False
                refresh_map = True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                for option in options:
                    if option.text == "QUIT" and option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                        in_menu = False
                        done = True
                    if option.text == "NEW GAME" and option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                        #read config from files
                        r = ConfigReader()
                        f = open('map_config', 'r')
                        map_config = r.read_config(f)
                        f.close()
                        f = open('character_config', 'r')
                        character_config = r.read_config(f)
                        f.close()

                        m = r.build_from_config(map_config, character_config)
                        ai.m = m

                        m.turn_controller.reset()
                        selected_character = m.turn_controller.current_character
                        selected_action = None
                        within_range = selected_character.within_range(selected_character.range)   
                        text_to_display = None
                        mouse_pos = None
                        in_menu = False
                        refresh_map = True

        if new_time:
            old_time = new_time
        new_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if new_time and old_time:
            pygame.display.set_caption("fps: " + str(int(clock.get_fps())) + " ms: " + str(new_time-old_time))

        pygame.display.update()

    #------------------
    # The actual game

    if refresh_map:
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        # map, range and characters
        dirty_rects.append(blit_map(screen).inflate(20,20))
        render_range(screen)
        render_characters_and_objects(screen)
        # menu elements
        screen.blit(bottom_bar, (0, screen_h-28))
        if saved_text:
            text_to_display = saved_text
        render_end_turn_button(screen)
        use_buttons = render_action_menu(screen)
        render_char_info(screen)

        refresh_map = False

    # move the map with arrow keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if not (map_offset_x + map_fix_x) < (-map_w + tile_w / 2 - (screen_w - map_w)):
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]: 
            map_offset_x -= 10
            refresh_map = True
    if not (map_offset_x + map_fix_x) > (map_w - tile_w / 2 + (screen_w - map_w)):
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            map_offset_x += 10
            refresh_map = True
    if not (map_offset_y) < (-map_h + tile_h / 2):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            map_offset_y -= 10
            refresh_map = True
    if not (map_offset_y) > (map_h - tile_h / 2 + (screen_h - map_h)):
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            map_offset_y += 10
            refresh_map = True


    #Handle mouse and keyboard events

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Quit if window is closed
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        # Use Esc to go into pause menu
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            in_menu = True
            paused = True
            continue

        # If not in menu
        else:
            # get mouse position and convert to cartesian coordinates
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            mx = mouse_pos[0]
            my = mouse_pos[1]

            # Update buttons if mouse moves in or out
            # End button
            if ( (end_turn_button.hovered and not end_turn_button.rect.collidepoint((mx,my))) or (not end_turn_button.hovered and end_turn_button.rect.collidepoint((mx,my))) ):  
                dirty_rects.append(render_end_turn_button(screen))
            else:
                # Action buttons
                for button in use_buttons:
                    if (button.hovered and not button.rect.collidepoint((mx,my))) or (not button.hovered and button.rect.collidepoint((mx,my))):
                        use_buttons = render_action_menu(screen)
                        for button in use_buttons:
                            dirty_rects.append(button.rect)  


            # Handle mouse clicks
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                # Reset button states
                end_turn_button.pushed = False
                for use_btn in use_buttons:
                    use_btn.pushed = False

                # Recognize end turn button
                if end_turn_button.rect.collidepoint((mx,my)):
                    # get current and next character
                    old_character = selected_character
                    text_to_display = m.turn_controller.current_character.end_turn()
                    selected_character = m.turn_controller.current_character
                    # update range with new character
                    if not selected_character.ai:
                        within_range = selected_character.within_range(selected_character.range)
                    else:
                        within_range = []

                    selected_action = None
                    refresh_map = True
                    wait_ms = ai_delay
                    continue

                # recognize action use buttons
                else:
                    for use_btn in use_buttons:
                        if use_btn.rect.collidepoint((mx,my)):
                            selected_action = selected_character.actions[use_buttons.index(use_btn)]
                            within_range = selected_character.within_range(selected_action.range, for_action = True)
                            selected_character.has_moved = True
                            refresh_map = True
                            break

                # Convert clicked coordinates to game map coordinates
                # map mouse x = mmx, map mouse y = mmy, i.e. which square on the map was clicked
                mouse_pos_map = screen_to_map(mx,my, map_offset_x, map_offset_y)
                mmx = mouse_pos_map[0]
                mmy = mouse_pos_map[1]

                # Handle game events resulting from clicks: set movement or action target square

                # if there is a square at the selected coordinates, i.e. if the click was inside the map
                if m.get_square_at(Coordinates(mmx, mmy)):
                    square_clicked = m.get_square_at(Coordinates(mmx, mmy))

                    # if a square outside range was clicked
                    if not square_clicked in within_range:
                        text_to_display = "Not within range."
                        continue
                    # if square inside range and the character has not moved, set walk target
                    elif selected_character.has_turn() and not selected_character.has_moved:
                        target_map_loc = Coordinates(mmx, mmy)
                        walk = True
                    # if an action was selected and the square clicked is in the action range
                    elif selected_action and square_clicked in within_range:
                        target_map_loc = Coordinates(mmx, mmy)
                        action = True


    #if AI's turn, get AI movement or action

    # get movement if the AI character has not moved
    if selected_character.ai and not selected_character.has_moved and not wait_ms:
        target_map_loc = ai.get_next_move()
        # If gets a target, move, otherwise proceed to action
        if target_map_loc:
            print(str(selected_character) + " moving to " + str(target_map_loc))
            walk = True
        else:
            selected_character.has_moved = True
    # get action if the AI character has moved
    elif selected_character.ai and selected_character.has_moved and not wait_ms:
        selected_action, target_map_loc = ai.get_action()
        # If gets a target, perform the action, else end turn
        if target_map_loc:
            action = True
            print(str(selected_character) + " chose action " + str(selected_action) + " to use on location " + str(target_map_loc))
        else:
            #update character infos for current character, action target character, and the next turn character
            old_character = selected_character
            selected_character.end_turn()
            selected_character = m.turn_controller.current_character

            dirty_rects += render_char_info(screen, [selected_character, old_character])
            #clear range
            within_range = selected_character.within_range(selected_character.range)
            refresh_map = True
            continue

    #Walk, if a walk target was set

    if walk:
        # remove range
        blit_map(screen)

        # set target map coordinates and get the shortest path there
        path = selected_character.get_shortest_path(target_map_loc)
        # walk the shortest path
        for step in path:

            # get the current map and screen locations
            current_map_loc = selected_character.location
            current_scr_loc = map_to_screen(selected_character.location.x, selected_character.location.y, map_offset_x, map_offset_y)

            # set the target screen location for the current step
            step_scr_target = map_to_screen(step.x, step.y, map_offset_x, map_offset_y)

            # determine if the character has walk sprites and prepare the animation
            walk_animation = False
            if len(selected_character.walk_sprites) > 0:
                nr_of_sprites = len(selected_character.walk_sprites)
                half_speed = True
                frame_counter = 0
                sprite_counter = 0
                walk_animation = True

            # move the character according to the shortest path step
            if step.x == current_map_loc.x and step.y < current_map_loc.y:
                selected_character.facing = direction.UP
                facing = "up"
            elif step.x == current_map_loc.x and step.y > current_map_loc.y:
                selected_character.facing = direction.DOWN
                facing = "down"
            elif step.x < current_map_loc.x and step.y == current_map_loc.y:
                selected_character.facing = direction.LEFT
                facing = "left"
            elif step.x > current_map_loc.x and step.y == current_map_loc.y:
                selected_character.facing = direction.RIGHT
                facing = "right"

            dirty_rects_moving = []

            #----------------
            # Walk loop

            # while the character has not reached the target
            while not current_scr_loc == step_scr_target:
                clock.tick(0)
                map_rect = blit_map(screen)

                pygame.event.pump()

                # if walk sprites available
                if walk_animation:
                    # if animation is set to half speed, may look too fast if full speed
                    if half_speed and frame_counter % 2 == 0:
                        if sprite_counter < nr_of_sprites - 1:
                            sprite_counter += 1
                        else:
                            sprite_counter = 0

                    frame_counter += 1 
                    dirty_rects_moving += render_characters_and_objects(screen, selected_character, current_scr_loc, sprite_counter)

                # if no walk sprites or if in target
                else:
                    dirty_rects_moving += render_characters_and_objects(screen, selected_character, current_scr_loc)

                # move the character on screen according to the shortest path step
                if facing == "up":
                    current_scr_loc = (current_scr_loc[0] + 2, current_scr_loc[1] - 1)
                elif facing == "down":
                    current_scr_loc = (current_scr_loc[0] - 2, current_scr_loc[1] + 1)
                elif facing == "left":
                    current_scr_loc = (current_scr_loc[0] - 2, current_scr_loc[1] - 1)
                elif facing == "right":
                    current_scr_loc = (current_scr_loc[0] + 2, current_scr_loc[1] + 1)

                # if map goes under the menus
                if map_rect.colliderect(bottom_menu_rect):
                    screen.blit(bottom_bar, (0, screen_h-28))
                    render_end_turn_button(screen)
                    use_buttons = render_action_menu(screen)

                #display fps and milliseconds between frames
                if new_time:
                    old_time = new_time
                new_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                if old_time and new_time:
                    pygame.display.set_caption("fps: " + str(int(clock.get_fps())) + " ms: " + str(new_time-old_time))

                #print([str(r) for r in dirty_rects_moving])
                pygame.display.update(dirty_rects_moving)
                #did_update_already = True
                dirty_rects_moving = []

            # walk loop end
            #----------------

            #move in the background logic
            selected_character.move_to_coordinates(step)

        # if all steps were successful    
        else:
            blit_map(screen)
            dirty_rects += render_characters_and_objects(screen)
            pygame.display.update(dirty_rects)

        text_to_display = "Choose action."
        refresh_map = True
        path_to_move = False
        walk = False

        if selected_character.ai:
            wait_ms = ai_delay

        #did_update_already = True    

    # don't display range after the character has moved
    if selected_character.has_moved and not selected_action:
        within_range = []


    #If an action target was set

    if action:
        square = m.get_square_at(target_map_loc)

        # set the correct facing direction for the attacking character
        if target_map_loc.x == selected_character.location.x and target_map_loc.y < selected_character.location.y:
            selected_character.facing = direction.UP
        elif target_map_loc.x == selected_character.location.x and target_map_loc.y > selected_character.location.y:
            selected_character.facing = direction.DOWN
        elif target_map_loc.x < selected_character.location.x and target_map_loc.y == selected_character.location.y:
            selected_character.facing = direction.LEFT
        elif target_map_loc.x > selected_character.location.x and target_map_loc.y == selected_character.location.y:
            selected_character.facing = direction.RIGHT

        # perform action
        text_to_display = selected_action.perform(target_map_loc)
        # display red or green text with action strength above the action target
        effect_text_loc = target_map_loc
        if square.has_character():
            effect_text = get_effect_text(selected_action)
        # reset selected action
        selected_action = None
        action = False
        #update character infos for current character, action target character, and the next turn character
        old_character = selected_character
        selected_character.end_turn()
        selected_character = m.turn_controller.current_character

        dirty_rects += render_char_info(screen,[square.character, selected_character, old_character])
        #clear range
        within_range = selected_character.within_range(selected_character.range)
        refresh_map = True

        if old_character.ai:
            wait_ms = ai_delay

        #continue




    if effect_text:
        effect_fade_count, effect_text = render_effect_text(screen, effect_fade_count, effect_text)
        # if was not reset
        if effect_text:
            dirty_rects.append(effect_text.get_rect().inflate(0,2))
        refresh_map = True

    # skip render if the screen was already updated in an inner loop
    if did_update_already:
        continue

    # if buttons need to be refreshed
    if end_turn_button.dirty:
        dirty_rects.append(render_end_turn_button(screen))
        end_turn_button.dirty = False
    for button in use_buttons:
        if button.dirty:
            render_action_menu(screen)
            dirty_rects.append(button.rect)
            button.dirty = False
            break

    if text_to_display:
        text_rect = render_info_text(screen, text_to_display)
        dirty_rects.append(text_rect)
        saved_text = text_to_display
        text_to_display = None

    # show fps and milliseconds
    if new_time:
        old_time = new_time
    new_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if new_time and old_time:
        pygame.display.set_caption("fps: " + str(int(clock.get_fps())) + " ms: " + str(new_time-old_time))

    #print([str(r) for r in dirty_rects])
    pygame.display.update(dirty_rects)

    if wait_ms > 0:
        wait_ms -= (new_time - old_time)
    elif wait_ms <= 0:
        wait_ms = False

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 4):

There's way too much code here (842 lines!) to try to give it a meaningful review. So I'll just make some general observations.

1. You could organize much of this code into methods on the classes you have. For example, the function `render_characters_and_objects` draws characters and objects. You could move the code for rendering a character into a `render` method on the `Character` class, and move the code for drawing an object into a `render` method on the `MapObject` class.
2. Basically, you should scrutinize every piece of code and ask the question, "would this code be clearer if it were turned into a method on a class?"
3. Code that deals with positions (like the `map_to_screen` function) should use position objects (possibly your `Coordinates` class?) instead of two numbers `x` and `y`.
4. Global variables make code hard to understand. For example, a lot of the code you posted uses on a global variable called `m` belonging to the `Map` class. These functions need to be methods on that class.
5. Again, you should scrutinize every global variable and ask the question, "does this variable really belong to an instance of some class?" For example, surely `map_w`, `map_h`, `map_offset_x` and `map_offset_y` ought to be properties of the `Map` instance? Could the `sprites` array lookups be avoided by storing a character's sprites in a property on the `Character` instance?
6. I wouldn't bother with collecting dirty rectangles. This adds a bunch of complexity that you don't need. Keep it simple and redraw the whole screen every frame.
7. A typical organization of game code is to give each object an `update` or `tick` method, which updates the object's internal state for one time interval, and a `draw` or `render` method that displays the object on the screen. Then in each game step the main loop just calls the `update` method on every object, and then the `render` method on every object. All the details of how each object updates and renders can be encapsulated within the object itself.
8. For example, at the moment you have the walking logic in its own loop: this means, I think, that only one character can walk at a time. It would be better for each character to have a `state` property; when this is set to `WALKING` then their `update` method causes them to take the next step towards the target and their `render` method picks the appropriate animation frame. Then you wouldn't need a separate game loop to handle the walking logic.